# How to check how many digits the number value has in roblox studio using a script?

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a Computer PIN cracking game in roblox.
But I don't know how to  check how many digits the number value has, so I come here to ask.

If you guys want to play my game, [Click Here](https://web.roblox.com/games/11455612774/Computer-PIN-Cracking-Simulator)

I just did this because I expect that nil can do the job, but no, they can't

```
if game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value == {nil, nil, nil, nil} then
    script.Parent.PlaceholderText = "Four Digits PIN"
elseif game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value == {nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil} then
    script.Parent.PlaceholderText = "Six Digits PIN"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use: `math.ceil(math.log(game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value))`

if this doesn't work for you there are multiple other ways to solve this that are discussed here:

https://devforum.roblox.com/t/best-way-to-find-how-many-digits-in-a-number/833942

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the Password.Value is a string. You can just use the length operator.

```lua
local password = game.ReplicatedStorage.Password.Value

local passwordLength = #password
assert(passwordLength > 0, "The password cannot be empty")
local numberWords = {
    "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six"
}
local message = string.format("%s Digit PIN", numberWords[passwordLength] or tostring(passwordLength))

local Placeholder = script.Parent.Placeholder
Placeholder.Text = message
```

Comment: I am getting an error, it said " attempt to get length of a number value" in line 3